# How to make this mug of beer work in Eeevee and not just in Cycles?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass, reflection

I have a mug of beer I'm working with which is composed of three elements: foam, beer, and the glass mug.

In Cycles it looks reasonable as one would expect:

[image]

However, in Eevee, I can't see the beer liquid in the glass unless the glass is removed from display:

[image]
[image]

It seems in Eevee, the glass "hides" the beer liquid.

Is there any way to make this work in Eevee?

My presumption is Eevee only allows refraction through one object at a time, and for this to work, I need to refract through two objects in series (the glass, then the beer liquid).

Is there any Eevee solution? Here is the blend file: https://easyupload.io/ii14h7

Thanks for any solutions/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to the very nature of how EEVEE "approximates" things such as reflections and refractions (transparency and caustics), quality will always be much diminished compared to Cycles - Expecially when trying to view a material with transparency through another material with transparency. You can try something like the graph below to get *closer* to what you're looking for, but EEVEE will never look as "correct" or "clean" as Cycles in this department. Don't forget to change the material's Blend Mode to Alpha-Blend:

[image: Refracteevee]